# How to interpret Fiware CYGNUS stats service output?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

Starting from my own installation of the following Fiware components: Orion Context Broker, CYGNUS NGSI, Fiware STH and MongoDB, after a while I got the following result consuming a stats service which I found inside [CYGNUS management API](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/management_interface/).

**Service:** `GET http://<cygnus_host>:<management_port>/v1/stats`

**Result:**

```
{
  "success":"true",
  "stats":{
     "sources":[
        {
           "name":"http-source",
           "status":"START",
           "setup_time":"2018-05-10T13:35:06.194Z",
           "num_received_events":78,
           "num_processed_events":78
        }
     ],
     "channels":[
        {
           "name":"sth-channel",
           "status":"START",
           "setup_time":"2018-05-10T13:35:06.662Z",
           "num_events":1,
           "num_puts_ok":78,
           "num_puts_failed":0,
           "num_takes_ok":77,
           "num_takes_failed":112
        },
        {
           "name":"mongo-channel",
           "status":"START",
           "setup_time":"2018-05-10T13:35:06.662Z",
           "num_events":0,
           "num_puts_ok":78,
           "num_puts_failed":0,
           "num_takes_ok":78,
           "num_takes_failed":139
        },
        {
           "name":"hdfs-channel",
           "status":"START",
           "setup_time":"2018-05-10T13:35:06.662Z",
           "num_events":1,
           "num_puts_ok":78,
           "num_puts_failed":0,
           "num_takes_ok":77,
           "num_takes_failed":35
        }
     ],
     "sinks":[
        {
           "name":"hdfs-sink",
           "status":"START",
           "setup_time":"2018-05-10T13:35:06.341Z",
           "num_processed_events":77,
           "num_persisted_events":0
        },
        {
           "name":"mongo-sink",
           "status":"START",
           "setup_time":"2018-05-10T13:35:06.374Z",
           "num_processed_events":78,
           "num_persisted_events":78
        },
        {
           "name":"sth-sink",
           "status":"START",
           "setup_time":"2018-05-10T13:35:06.380Z",
           "num_processed_events":78,
           "num_persisted_events":77
        }
     ]
  } 
}
```

What caught my attention was the amount of **num_takes_failed** on each channel and here is my first question:

**What exactly does this variable mean?**

Looking into CYGNUS [documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/management_interface_v1.md) I suppose that a "take" is something like a retry of a certain action in Flume Mongo channel but which action is that?

I looked at the MongoDB log files and did not find anything related to a connection saturation or similar problem, which brings me to my second question.

**Should I worry about this statistic? If yes, how do I solve this problem?**

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to be worried about the **num_takes_failed** if you see that the number of processed_events is the same than the number of persisted_events. The numb_takes_filed is the result of the subtraction between the values of the flume methods **EventTakeAttemptCount** and **EventTakeSuccessCount** where the **EventTakeAttemptCount** is the total number of times the sink(s) attempted to read the events from the channel. This doesn't mean that the events were returned each time since sinks might poll and the channel might not have any data, On the other hand,**EventTakesuccessCount** is the total number of events that were successfully taken by the sink(s).

Moreover, if you want to know more about how the events are processed by the channels and sinks, you can run Cygnus on debug mode and see the log output for ensuring that every event is processed and persisted in the correct way